# Sync text file on certain fields only

Tags: synchronization, text-files

I have a PLIST file like that:

```
    <key>background_0</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>Picture</string>
        <key>Position</key>
        <string>{239.5,160}</string>
        <key>Sizes</key>
        <string>{480,320}</string>
        <key>Scale</key>
        <string>{1.0,1.0}</string>
```

And this file has many blocks like this.
I'd like to change only certain fields (**POSITION, SIZES**), and don't change other.

So let's say i'll produce same file with fields I need, and exclude those unneeded fields. (Type must remain type, and Scale must remain Scale)

So if I have file like

```
A A
B B
```

Then I add a file

```
C C
D D
```

And **exclude first string** the result must be

```
A A
D D
```

I know tha **SED** can help me, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it by myself. Thanks anyway.

[Tortoise](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/?source=dlp)